# How to create an edge list from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, network-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe (df) of the form-

```
    Col1
A  [Green,Red,Purple]
B  [Red, Yellow, Blue]
C  [Brown, Green, Yellow, Blue]
```

I need to convert this to an edge list i.e. a dataframe of the form:

```
Source    Target    Weight
  A         B         1
  A         C         1
  B         C         2
```

**EDIT**
Note that the new dataframe has rows equal to the total number of possible pairwise combinations. Also, to compute the 'Weight' column, we simply find the intersection between the two lists. For instance, for B&C, the elements share two colors: Blue and Yellow. Therefore, the 'Weight' for the corresponding row is 2.

What is the fastest way to do this? The original dataframe contains about 28,000 elements.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear how you want to get from the first to second.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The lists for each element are being compared pairwise. For example, for A-B, the elements have one element in common (Red). Therefore, the weight for Source-A Target-B row is 1. In total, the new dataframe would have all pairwise combinations of the original dataframe rows.

Comment: When you say 28k elements do you mean rows/nodes?  If so, doing a generate all combinations approach will be quite [large](https://www.google.com/search?q=28000+choose+2&oq=28000+cho&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0.6150j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Yes @BobHaffner! That is currently a huge problem I have to work around.

Comment: If your dataframe is well-defined (i.e. every row has the same number of elements). You can easily do this with pd.melt().  Its not clear why you'd want to store lists instead a dataframe -- seems to defeat the purpose of using dataframes

Comment: @mortonjt it was the output of a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, starting off with the dataframe:

```
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Col1': [['Green','Red','Purple'], 
                 ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue'], 
                 ['Brown', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue']]
     }, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply(set)    
df

                           Col1
A          {Purple, Red, Green}
B           {Red, Blue, Yellow}
C  {Green, Yellow, Blue, Brown}
```

Each list in `Col1` has been converted into a set to find the union efficiently. Next, we'll use `itertools.combinations` to create pairwise combinations of all rows in `df`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=list(combinations(df.index.tolist(), 2)), 
    columns=['Src', 'Dst'])

df1

  Src Dst
0   A   B
1   A   C
2   B   C
```

Now, apply a function to take the union of the sets and find its length. The `Src` and `Dst` columns act as a lookup into `df`.

```
df1['Weights'] = df1.apply(lambda x: len(
    df.loc[x['Src']]['Col1'].intersection(df.loc[x['Dst']]['Col1'])), axis=1)
df1

  Src Dst  Weights
0   A   B        1
1   A   C        1
2   B   C        2
```

I advice set conversion at the very beginning. Converting your lists to a set each time on the fly is expensive and wasteful.

For more speedup, you'd probably want to *also* copy the sets into two columns in the new dataframe because calling `df.loc` constantly will slow it down a notch.

Comment: I think we using same method , but your is better upvote ~

Comment: @Wen Sorry! I wrote my answer independent of yours. There are some subtle differences, but they are similar in many aspects. I believe you deserve a +1 too :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this. Not very neat but work. *PS: The final out put you can adjust it , I did not drop columns and change the columns name*

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[['Green','Red','Purple'],['Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue'],['Brown', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue']],"two":['A','B','C']})
df=df.set_index('two')
del df.index.name
from itertools import combinations
DF=pd.DataFrame()
dict1=df.T.to_dict('list')
DF=pd.DataFrame(data=[x for x in combinations(df.index, 2)])
DF['0_0']=DF[0].map(df['Col1'])
DF['1_1']=DF[1].map(df['Col1'])
DF['Weight']=DF.apply(lambda x : len(set(x['0_0']).intersection(x['1_1'])),axis=1)



DF
Out[174]: 
   0  1                   0_0                           1_1  Weight
0  A  B  [Green, Red, Purple]           [Red, Yellow, Blue]       1
1  A  C  [Green, Red, Purple]  [Brown, Green, Yellow, Blue]       1
2  B  C   [Red, Yellow, Blue]  [Brown, Green, Yellow, Blue]       2
```

Answer (score 2):

- get an array of sets
- get pairwise indices representing all combinations using `np.triu_indices`
- use `&` operator to get the pairwise intersections and get lengths via a comprehension

---

```
c = df.Col1.apply(set).values

i, j = np.triu_indices(c.size, 1)

pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Source=df.index[i],
        Target=df.index[j],
        Weight=[len(s) for s in c[i] & c[j]]
    ))

  Source Target  Weight
0      A      B       1
1      A      C       1
2      B      C       2
```